# Formatting a date using jQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I request a date from datepicker by this line:

```
var checkIn=jQuery(".booking-date-fields).datepicker('getDate');
```

The output is:

```
Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (Morocco Standard Time)
```

How can I format this using php or javascript to a YYYY-MM-DD format:

```
2015-12-02
```

Help help please !!!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

Comment: I use moment.js... http://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP you convert the string to UNIX time with [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) and convert it as you wish with the [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function:

```
//$_GET['checkIn']  = 'Wed Dec 02 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000';
$getDate = $_GET['checkIn'];
$date = strtotime( substr( $getDate, 0, strpos( $getDate, '(' ) ) );
echo date( 'Y-m-d', $date );
// Output "2015-12-02"
```

**Edit** An ugly but working fix...

Comment: my url is : http://localhost:8081/villaGioconda/bookingStep2.php?checkIn=Wed+Dec+02+2015+00%3A00%3A00+GMT%2B0000+(Morocco+Standard+Time)

i have code :

$getDate=$_GET['checkIn'];
$date = strtotime($getDate);
echo date( 'Y-m-d', $date );

but i get in return 1970-01-01 !!! i must have output "2015-12-02"

Comment: I had to remove the parenthesis from the string. Now it should work!